# How to handle select ng-change to get selected option's text?

Tags: angularjs

what is the proper way to set vm.woExtend.ProgressNote to selected text?

**How to get a reference to the selected option in ng-change ??**

When I select option1, I want to set vm.woExtend.ProgressNote to "Option1 Text"

```
<select ng-model="vm.woExtend.Reason" ng-change="vm.woExtend.ProgressNote='?????'">
    <option value="1">Option1 Text</option>
    <option value="2">Option3 Text</option>
    <option value="3">Option4 Text</option>
</select>
<textarea ng-bind="vm.woExtend.ProgressNote"></textarea>
```

Comment: First of all please set different value for different option first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this when you have the option list defined on your controller, so then you are able to assign a value to the progress note property (e.g. `vm.woExtend.ProgressNote = vm.woExtend.Reason.text`).

The following snippet implements the solution described.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function () {
    this.ReasonOptions = [
      { value: "1", text : "Option1 Text" },
      { value: "2", text : "Option3 Text" },
      { value: "3", text : "Option4 Text" }
    ];
   this.woExtend = {
     Reason: 1,
     ProgressNote: 'Blah bla bl!'
   };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
  <select
    ng-model="vm.woExtend.Reason"
    ng-options="option as option.text for (key, option) in vm.ReasonOptions"
    ng-change="vm.woExtend.ProgressNote = vm.woExtend.Reason.text">
  </select>
  <textarea ng-bind="vm.woExtend.ProgressNote"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller have an object like:

```
 vm.ProgressNote = {"1": "Option1 Text", "2": "Option2 Text"};
```

Then it becomes trivial:

```
 ng-change="vm.woExtend.ProgressNote = vm.ProgressNote[vm.woExtend.Reason]"
```

Even that probably I wouldn't do this in in ng-change event, but in a watch for vm.woExtend.Reason inside the controller.

Comment: Naming is non important, if ProgressNote already exists, call it ProgressNoteDescription.

Comment: its a string, I need to set it to slected text FROM the select control

Comment: The selected option is bound to vm.woExtend.Reason (as you are defining the ng-model for the select), hence you need somehow to link that selected option to the text of the select (unless you want to some jquery stuff to fetch it), you can create an object that links the option values to its texts in vm.ProgressNote, and in ng-change by using vm.ProgressNote[vm.woExtend.Reason] you get the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ngOptions (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

In your case, you would create an object via your controller:

```
$scope.mySelect={}
$scope.myOptions=[
    {value=1, label='Option 1 Text'},
    {value=2, label='Option 2 Text'},
    {value=3, label='Option 3 Text'}
]
```

Then in your html have:

```
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="option.label for option in myOptions">
</select>
```

After select is made, you can get the text by:

```
var text=$scope.mySelect.label
```